# Prove that an inner product is positive definite.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, group-actions, isometry

Let $V$ be a 2-dimensional real vector space and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ a non-degenerate inner product on $V$. Consider a function $f:SO(3)\times V\to V$ such that:

(1) for all $A\in SO(3)$, the map $f(A,\cdot)=f_A:V\to V$ is a linear isometry.

(2) $f_I$ is the identity map on $V$.

(3) $f(A\cdot B,v)=f\big(A,f(B,v)\big)$ for all $A,B\in SO(3)$ and $v\in V$.

> If the following statement is true:
>   *given $u,v\in V$ with $\langle u,u\rangle=\langle v,v\rangle$ then there exists $A\in SO(3)$ such that $f_A(v)=u$*, how could we conclude that $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is positive definite?

Comment: I don't think you can conclude this : the opposite of your inner product satisfies the same conditions. But maybe you can conlude that $\langle v,v\rangle$ has the same sign for all $v\in V$.

Comment: Isn't positive definiteness part of the definition of an inner product?

Comment: is it important that it is $SO(3)$ and $\dim V=2$? Find a isometric isomorphism from $V$ into $\mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ then rotate $u$ to $v$ ...